# Swift combine: assign value in .sink, but can't use .assign

Tags: swift, combine

```
    $overallSecondsLeft
    .map
    { ti -> String? in
        let seconds = (ti.rounded(.up))
        if seconds > 0
        {
            return { String(format: "%02d:%02d", $0.0, $0.1) }(seconds.minutesAndSecondsOverHours)
        }
        return nil
    }
    .assign(to: \.timerText, on: bv)
    .store(in: &cancellables)
```

does not work. I mean - nothing happens. map returns string, but this string do not come in timerText.

Variant

```
    $overallSecondsLeft
    .map
    { ti -> String? in
        let seconds = (ti.rounded(.up))
        if seconds > 0
        {
            return { String(format: "%02d:%02d", $0.0, $0.1) }(seconds.minutesAndSecondsOverHours)
        }
        return nil
    }
    .sink{ bv.timerText = $0 }
    .store(in: &cancellables)
```

works correctly.

Environment:

```
class BView: UIView {
    ...
    var timerText: String? {
        get { ... }
        set { ... }
    }
    ...
}
guard let bv = view as? BView else { return }
```

Obviously, the question is: w..?

*I found an advice to add .receive(on: RunLoop.main) before .assign, but it did not help.*

Comment: What do you mean by "does not work"? What is the error message? Does it compile but crashes?

Comment: You are using too many optionals. Combine relies on either value or error.

Comment: I mean - nothing happens. map returns string, but this string do not come in timerText.

Comment: When you set up the pipeline is bv not nil?

Comment: LuLuGaGa, after guard?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that `timerText` variable is a computed property. The `assign(to:on:)` works on a KVO-compliant property of an object, and a computed property is not KVO compliant, if you remove the get/set it will work.
Also please note that `assign(to:on:)` [maintains a strong reference](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/combine/publisher/assign(to:on:)) to object so you do not have to store the result to the cancellables.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not the reason. It is not first computed property in my application which is used in this way.

Comment: I have tested the above example with a property that does not have a custom get/set and it worked fine, can you pls make a small code change and check?

Comment: Of course it was the first assumption but not confirmed. I have several computed properties which work with .assign(to:on:), and I have several stored properties which do not. I can't understand the pattern.